# Handle ClientResponse by aiohttp in function

Tags: python, python-asyncio, response, aiohttp

I'm using `aiohttp` to get and test proxies (creating my first package [proxy-master](https://github.com/555Russich/proxy_master))

I want to write function which would handle `ClientResponse` after calling `.gather()` like that:

```
async def async_test_proxies(proxies: list, url: str = 'icanhazip.com', enable_prints: bool = False) -> list:
    def is_proxy_works(html: str, proxy: str, url: str, enable_prints: bool) -> bool:
        ...

    proxies_works = []
    async with ClientSession() as s:
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(session_request(s, url, proxy)) for proxy in proxies]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        for i in range(len(results)):
            r = handle_response(results[i])
            if type(r) is str:
                if is_proxy_works(r, proxies[i], url, enable_prints) is True:
                    proxies_works.append(proxies[i])
    print(f'{len(proxies_works)}/{len(proxies)} proxies works') if enable_prints else ...
    return proxies_works


async def session_request(s: ClientSession, url: str, proxy: str, timeout: int = 3) -> ClientResponse:
    async with s.get(
            f'https://{url}',
            proxy=f'http://{proxy}',
            timeout=timeout
    ) as r:
        return r


def handle_response(r: ClientResponse) -> bool | str:
    match r.status:
        case 200:
            return str(r.text())
        case _:
            return False


print(test_proxies(get_proxies_from_txt(), enable_prints=True))
```

**Error**:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientResponse.text' was never awaited
  return str(r.text())
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

**Question**: Why coroutine `ClientResponse.text` was never awaited if i used await here

`results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)`

to wait results? Any possible to write `responseHandler` function...?

**Question_2**: offtop but.. Does `.gather()` guarantee to return responses in the same sequence as input tasks?

Comment: I worked with asyncio for a project in the past. I always encountered problems like this whenever I tried to do something like what your `session_request` method does. Instead of returning `r`, try using it immediately in the method that creates it.

Comment: Update: on your `return str(r.text())` line, `r.text()` itself must be awaited.

Comment: @topal i already changed to ‘return str(await r.text())’ and made this func async, but got another error. Smth like: Session already closed

Comment: I suggest you put the whole task that you need run async into one method. So that includes sending the request & also processing it. So you should end up *not* passing ClientSession & ClientResponse objects to other methods. This is what worked for me, as I also tried more or less what your code is doing. I do have a code sample I can post as part of an answer if that'd help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here, as I noted in my comment on your question, is an example of how I used `asyncio` with `aiohttp` to send requests & parse responses. Perhaps this will be of some help.

This example is based on part of a larger project.

**Class `RequestTask`**:

```
# Created & used in the designated main `asyncio` method in your application.
class RequestTask:
  def __init__(self, parent_object, session, request):
    self.__session = session
    self.__parent_object = parent_object # parent_object is responsible for processing.
    self.request = request
    self.task = asyncio.create_task(self.__post())

  async def __post(self):
    async with self.__session.post(<url & body>) as response:
      content = await response.content.read()

      if response.ok:
        await self.__parent_object.process_response(content)
      else:
        content = content.decode('utf-8')
        print('Error:', content)
        print('Request:\n{}\n'.format(self.request.decode('utf-8')))

    return response
```

In the main asyncio method, I would create however many `RequestTask` objects I need, in some sort of iterable like a `list` or `tuple`. The `RequestTask` init method creates a new `Task` for the `__post` method, something now must `await` it.

**Method `__main_sync_method`**:

```
# This is the main async method that is run, belonging to `parent_object` in `RequestTask`.
async def __main_async_method(self):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    # An example tuple of RequestTasks.
    tasks = ( RequestTask(self, session, request1), RequestTask(self, session, request2), ..., ..., ... )
    print('Total number of tasks: {}'.format(len(tasks)))

    if tasks: # Or some kind of while loop that won't end until all Tasks are properly complete.
      print('Processing {} jobs...'.format(len(tasks)))
      await asyncio.wait([ rt.task for rt in tasks ]) # now wait on all of the tasks to be complete.

      # Now you can do other special handling of Task statuses.
      # Print all of the response statuses of the Tasks.
      print(', '.join(rt.task.result().status for rt in tasks if rt.task.done()))
```

Let me know whether or not this is any help.

Another thing, when I worked on this project, Windows' version of Python 3.8 had some bug with `asyncio` or `aiohttp` where the code would run fine, but the sessions would close too quickly & display errors. This was in the past 6 months I dealt with that.
[You can read more about this here.](https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914) Don't know if this applies to you or not, just thought I should give you fair warning.

Comment: Thanks for this example, but i think that answer to my first question is just no. In your code you are handling results in same function which initialize ClientSession. Now i'm handling response in `session_request` function and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but think that answer for

> Any possible to write responseHandler function...?

is **no**

I solved it by handling response in request function:

```
async def session_request(s: ClientSession, url: str, proxy: str, timeout: int = 3) -> ClientResponse | str:
    async with s.get(
            f'https://{url}',
            proxy=f'http://{proxy}',
            timeout=timeout
    ) as r:
        match r.status:
            case 200:
                return str(await r.text())
            case _:
                return r
```